# recording the url of error log

Tags: apache, error-handling, php, php-ini

I am setting up an error log , but I can't get the urls where the errors occurred

So if the error happens on `http://example.com/birth/ee.php` I want this url to be in the log

here is my php.ini file

```
allow_url_include = 1
date.timezone = "Europe/Paris"
;;; log php errors
display_startup_errors = false
display_errors = false
html_errors = false
log_errors = true
track_errors = true
error_log = /home/mysperts/public_html/example.com/birth/php-errors.log
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
log_errors_max_len = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably need some custom logging for that...use something like [set_error_handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php%20set_error_handler) to set up something in the code to log when an exception happens or something.

Otherwise you can just match up timestamps with the access_log ;)